Android timer has imprecise period
I'm writing a metronome application for Android (none available on the Play Store fit my expectations).
I've tried several ways to schedule a sound periodically, but none of them provided me with the expected precision (especially with high BPMs / short periods).
I've used so far a java.util.Timer (example below) as well as a a single-thread scheduled executor and an android.os.CountDownTimer. The three of them has the same "beat spacing" imprecision.
import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import net.dericbourg.mymetronome.R
import java.util.Timer
import java.util.TimerTask

class Metronome {

    private val bpmConverter = BpmConverter()

    private var isPlaying = false
    private var timer = Timer()

    fun isPlaying(): Boolean {
        return isPlaying
    }

    fun play(bpm: Long, context: Context) {
        val playerTimeInterval = bpmConverter.bpmToDuration(bpm)
        val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.main_click)

        timer = Timer()
        timer.schedule(PlayTask(mediaPlayer), 0, playerTimeInterval.inWholeMilliseconds)
        isPlaying = true
    }

    fun stop() {
        timer.cancel()
        isPlaying = false
    }

    companion object {
        class PlayTask(private val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                mediaPlayer.start()
            }
        }
    }
}

What would be a way to schedule with high precision the period of those beats?

I would start by using ScheduledExecutorService. Then, I would focus on separating your problem. Is you problem not getting control at the right moments (i.e., ScheduledExecutorService is not invoking your code when you want)? Or is your problem getting media playback to happen instantaneously (i.e., MediaPlayer has too much latency and you need to use SoundPool). Also, have you examined existing open source metronomes to see what techniques they use?

Oh, good point! I did check at opensource. Looking at them, looks indeed that the culprit might be the MediaPlayer.

That does not surprise me. MediaPlayer is for longer-form content, ringtones on up. I'm assuming that your metronome is just playing a simple short tone. The simplest is ToneGenerator, though it's fairly inflexible. Otherwise, look at SoundPool. Once you come up with a solution that fits your needs, consider posting an answer!

I don't think you're going to get what you want.  For a metronome, you need highly precise timers going up to 200 or so hertz.  There is nothing on Android or the base OS of Linux that provides that precision.  First off, the OS is not realtime.  When you say "schedule me for 10 ms from now", there is no promise that you will be woken up in exactly 10ms.  You'll be woken up in 10ms or more.  It could be close, but depending on what else your device is doing (and the average device is doing a LOT in the background for other apps) you may be delayed significantly.  So creating a beat every timer tick is not going to give you the regular result you want.  You'd need a realtime OS for that, which Linux is not.
Secondly, timers do not have ms precision even under ideal circumstances. The best timer in the system tends to give 120hz signals, although this will vary by hardware.  That's not enough to do 200 bpm like a metronome needs-  it would need at least 200 hz.
Thirdly-  audio latency exists.  Sounds do not play the instant you call the function, and the amount of time it takes is not constant.  This alone is more than enough to break a metronome.
Probably your best bet is to not create a beat every tick.  It's to generate a sound file that's several seconds long with the tick at the frequency you want and play that sound file on repeat.  You don't have to have it in a file, you can generate the waveform in memory and play it from there.  But that will give you far better results than trying to do it in response to a tick.

I am a developer and a musician too and I've never found a good metronome in term of precision, there is always a tick out of 10 that is too soon or too late and that depends a lot on the hundreds of processes and threads in background. Maybe you can give maximum priority to you thread. But I am agree with the last sentence of @Gabe Sechan
